# Can anyone identify this phone PCB?

Tags: pcb, identification, telephone

Can anyone identify this mobile phone?

http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2010/10/29/what-is-that-electronic-thing-from-yemen/

http://www.flickr.com/photos/ladyada/5126516011/

[image]

http://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?p=1351

Answer (score 7):

Nokia 6120c

http://www.ownta.com/compatible-nokia-6120c-cell-phone-mainboard-with-power-ic-and-used-flash-ic-no-software.html

Answer from here:
http://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?p=1351

Commentary:
http://www.bunniestudios.com/blog/?p=1359

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's missing a board. The two connectors on the board probably connect to something of more importance like a processor board. Hidden under the shielded components is probably a chipset for running the GSM portion, but of course without seeing the components it's a blind guess. Maybe someone will recognise it, but it's not going to be easy to deduct.

My guess would be a low cost payphone. Certainly not a smartphone; sub £30 range.

Comment: Actually, from reading the comments on adafruit, the connectors could be to the keypad and LCD, with the bottom side of the board having the processor, but it's unclear.